# Understanding the concept of simple row compression in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I read that the row compression feature of SQL server reduces the space needed to store a row by only using the bytes required to store a given value. Without compression an int column needs 4 bytes. We need the whole 4 bytes only if we are storing the number 1 or 1 million. With row compression turned on, sql server looks at the actual value being stored and calculates the amount of storage needed.

What I don't understand - Why does 1 and 1mn need the full 4 bytes and why do the other numbers, bigger than 1 require lesser memory ?

**EDIT -** It is taken from the book: Delivering business intelligence with SQL server 2008

> Row compression reduces the space required to store a row of data. It does this by only
>   using the bytes required to store a given value. For example, without row compression, a
>   column of type int normally occupies 4 bytes. This is true if we are storing the number
>   1 or the number 1 million. SQL Server allocates enough space to store the maximum
>   value possible for the data type.
>   When row compression is turned on, SQL Server makes smarter space allocations.
>   It looks at the actual value being stored for a given column in a given row, and then
>   determines the storage required to represent that value. This is done to the nearest
>   whole byte.
>   Of course, this added complexity adds some overhead as data is inserted or updated
>   in the table. It also adds a smaller amount of overhead when data is retrieved from that
>   table. In most cases, the time taken for this additional processing is negligible. In fact,
>   in some cases, the saving in disk read and disk write time can even be greater than the
>   calculation time required for data compression.

Comment: Where did you read the part about how integers are stored?

Comment: When you think wrong about something you can not ask for why it is wrong.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Please see my edit for the source of information.

Comment: @MeysamTolouee - I understand. But, I want to get the correct information.

Comment: @Steam So ask the right question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 1 million are just examples of values that require 4 bytes if row compression is off. It does not mean that the other numbers require less space.

1 and 1 million was probably picked out as examples because 1 is small and 1 million is big.

An int will take 4 bytes regardless of what value it has if row compression is off.

Answer (score 2):

You're having wrong perception of this. Please read [the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576.aspx) thoroughly.